# apache cannot access public_html on CIFS

Tags: apache, samba, cifs, public-html

I have my computer on network, and whole homedir is mounted at login with CIFS. When I access http://localhost everything works fine, but when I access http://localhost/~user it fails.

```
# cat /etc/mtab
.....
//192.168.1.5/user/ /home/user cifs rw,mand 0 0


ls -l
...
drwxrwxrwx  37 user domain users         0 2011-12-22 09:12 public_html
```

The browser say:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /~lluisforns on this server.
```

And apache say

```
 cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
 [Thu Dec 22 18:19:09 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /~lluisforns denied
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, and it turned out to be an SELinux thing: SELinux has a setting that prevents httpd (apache) to follow CIFS links.

1. To see if you have this issue:

   getsebool -a | grep httpd

you should see httpd_use_cifs --> ***on***. if not, your in luck - this is your problem.

1. To fix:

   setsebool httpd_use_cifs on

You may also decide to disable SELinux altogether (assuming you know the risk) - here is a link to [one relevant page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/how-to-disable-selinux-redhat-fedora-debian-unix/)